# PSPACE completeness, with different kinds of reductions

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, complexity-classes, space-complexity

*PSPACE-complete$_{FP}$* problems are the *PSPACE* problems such that every other *PSPACE* problem can be transformed to it with a polynomial time reduction, i.e. the reduction is an algorithm $\in$ [*FP*](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fp). This class is known as *PSPACE-complete*.

Similarly, we can define :

*PSPACE-complete$_{FPSPACE}$* problems, the  *PSPACE* problems such that every other *PSPACE* problem can be transformed to it with a polynomial space reduction. This class is still *PSPACE*, minus trivial problems $\Sigma^*$ and $\emptyset$.

*PSPACE-complete$_{FNP}$* problems, the  *PSPACE* problems such that every other *PSPACE* problem can be transformed to it with a [*FNP*](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fnp) reduction (the function problem extension of the decision problem class *NP*).

*PSPACE-complete$_{FPH}$* problems, the  *PSPACE* problems such that every other *PSPACE* problem can be transformed to it with a *FPH* reduction (the function problem extension of the decision problem class *PH*).

It seems to me that all these classes are well defined and that we have :

*PSPACE-complete* $\subset$ *PSPACE-complete$_{FNP}$* $\subset$ *PSPACE-complete$_{FPH}$* $\subset$ *PSPACE*

Additionally, if *PSPACE-complete$_{FPH}$* $\neq$ *PSPACE-complete* then *P* $\neq$ *NP*.

Naturally, *PSPACE-complete$_{FNP}$* $\neq$ *PSPACE-complete* works also but it's more difficult to prove.

I suspect that *PSPACE-complete$_{FPH}$* is just *PSPACE*. What more can be found about the two last defined classes ?

Comment: Done : http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31797/pspace-completeness-with-different-kinds-of-reductions
Should I delete the question here ?

Comment: @FrançoisG. The question is ontopic here. Let's see if it attracts any attention; since there's a link to the crosspost, potential answerers can check there first.

Comment: A quite similar question : http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25316/nexptime-completeness-with-more-time-for-reductions

Comment: I'm closing this question because [it has been reposted on Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31797/pspace-completeness-with-different-kinds-of-reductions). Please visit that site for answers.